# Unable to install SQL Management Studio

Tags: windows-server-2008

When trying to install SQL Management Studio express I'm met with the following error

[image: Error]

But I have version 4 of the .net framework installed, so this shouldn't be a problem?

I'm running MS Server 2008 R2

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In Server 2008R2, the .Net Framework 3.5 should be installed through the Server *Features* (in the Server Manager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of the .NET framework don't completely replace older ones. If a program specifically requires an older version, then you need to install that version. So do what the error message suggests.

You can get .NET 3.5 SP1 here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4.0 is not a superset of .NET 3.5. If an application requires .NET 3.5 SP1 you **must** install .NET 3.5 SP1.